# neat method for iterator to list then concat

Tags: python, numpy, iterator

I'm trying to load pics with iterator, and then pass it to the next function.
My old way worked but slow:

```
data_set = np.array(next(generator))
for data in generator:
   data_set = np.concatenate((data_set, data), axis=0)
```

Now I was able to speed it up with list unpack method, but I'll have to turn it to list first, then concat.

```
data_set = np.array([*generator])
data_shape = data_set.shape
desird_shape = (data_shape[0] * data_shape[1], ) + data_shape[2:]
data_set = data_set.reshape(desird_shape)
```

***This method would not work if the items in the generator have different shape[0].***

Is this the best/neatest way to do this? I feel like there must be a better way than this.

Comment: `concatenate` takes a list of many arrays, not just 2.  `np.array` also takes a list, but adds a new leading dimension.

Comment: Got it! I forgot concat can takes more than 2 elements...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the reminder from @hpaulj, I was able to solve it by the following code.

```
data_set = np.array([*generator])
data_set = np.concatenate(data_set, axis=0)
```